# Css grid, how to size up element without them messing up the whole page

Tags: html, css

I have this issue I'm still getting on my code. I have added a snippet to visualise what I am saying. Basically I don't understand why my  content are not taking the full screen (`.statistiquesRight` should take the whole left side of the screen). But even when  I tried to  set it up with 100vh, but they appear but minimized.And the middle logo completly go nuts. I don't really get it.

(This is a projet to learn) Thank you very much <3

```css
@media (min-width: 1024px) {

  * {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;
  }


  .First-tp{
    background: rgb(254, 122, 255);
    background: linear-gradient(
      96deg,
      rgba(254, 122, 255, 1) 0%,
      rgba(55, 154, 237, 1) 67%
    );

  }

  .gridFirstTP{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
    height: 100vh;
  }

  .randonButton{
    grid-column: 2/2;
    grid-row: 2/2;
    display: grid;
    justify-content: center;
  }

  .headAlert{
    grid-column: .2/2;
    grid-row: 1/2;
    justify-content: center;
    display: grid;

  }

  .usrInput{
    grid-column: 1/1;
    grid-row: 1/3;
    margin-top: 300px;
  }

  .statistiquesRight{
    grid-column: 4/4;
    grid-row: 4/1;
    background: rgb(105, 177, 239);
    background: linear-gradient(
      21deg,
      rgba(105, 177, 239, 1) 0%,
      rgba(235, 119, 238, 1) 83%
    );
    box-shadow: -6px 0px 15px -4px;
    display: grid;
  }

  .secondBlock{
    background: red;
    height: 100vh;
  }




}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/large.css" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mini.css" /> -->
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />

    <title>NextOnEarth</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <!--Image de la terre-->
    <div class="First-tp">
      <div class="gridFirstTP">
        
        <div class="randonButton">
          <img
            src="images\earth.png"
            alt=""
            onclick="userInfo()"
          />
        </div>

        <div class="headAlert">
          <p>
            Connect toi, clique sur la terre et recherche des articles aléatoires sur le thème de l'environnement
          </p>
        </div>

        <!-- Pop-up, non connecte -->

        <!--Les informations perssonnels-->

        <div class="usrInput">
          <input
            type="text"
            name="firstName"
            id="input-Prenom"
            placeholder="Entrer votre Prenom"
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="lastName"
            id="input-Nom"
            placeholder="Entrer votre Nom"
          />
          <br />
          <br />
          <input
            type="text"
            name="email"
            id="input-email"
            placeholder="Entrer votre Email"
          />
        </div>

        <!--Statistique-->


        <div class="statistiquesRight">
            <h2 id="rightstats">-Les Statistiques-</h2>
           <span>
              <p class="articleStatsl">Nombre d'article visités:</p>
              <p class="articleStatsl" id="statspress">0</p>
            </span>
           </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

enter code here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 100vh - sets the full height of the **browser window**
2. Why do you use the grid first and then flex, you have to make up your mind.
3. Explain to me what you actually want to do. Do you want to divide the whole screen into 3 columns as shown in the screenshot?[Screen columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EJ91n.png)

Comment: Sorry for the delay, myself was sleeping hahahha.. So I'm kinda new, 1 I set 100vh on my first block to display it the same on every device, but for my second block which come after I didn't find any ohter solution than setting again the vh 100 again so oa second block is displayed again full heigh. 2 I don't really know, I tried both flex and grid to fix my issue, flex and then I moved to grid, but I don't really get where is the flex now, maybe the (display: flex) ? 3 Yes this is basically, I want to understand how to display it full width. Thank you so much

Comment: Hey I have figured it out I guess, Can you still check my code and see if it is somewhere close to "Clean" ? But thank your for helping it mean a lot... It's hard to understand everything at first sight, I read documentation but I feels not all topics are covered or I just don't really understand yet the concepts.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for, your description isn't very clear. I would suggest posting a screenshot of something showing what layout you are trying to achieve.

That being said, have you got this in your css?

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
}

html { height: 100%; }

body { min-height: 100%; }
```

Comment: Actually I solved my problem, this is why the snippet looks fine. But I wanted to know if the code is somewhere close to "Clean".. from a css perspective.